# create a hole in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of the form

```
$array = array(1 => 'a',
               2 => 'b',
               3 => 'c',
               4 => 'd')
```

and I would like to create a 'hole' between 2 and 3, i.e. obtain the following array

```
$array = array(1 => 'a',
               2 => 'b',
               4 => 'c',
               5 => 'd')
```

What do you reckon to be the best way to do this?

Comment: +1 for *hole in the array*. :)

Comment: [array_splice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) perhaps to insert a null value? Or simply create the array with defined keys in the first place

Comment: Try `array_shovel` :)

Comment: I think I'll try array_shovel!

Comment: You could create an array of keys and use `array_combine()` to combine the values

Comment: already indexed http://goo.gl/iWu1c7 (less then 15 minutes)

Comment: @vladkras: Most of the questions on Stack Overflow get indexed in less than 1 minute ;)

Comment: @AmalMurali [hmmm...](http://images.wikia.com/en.futurama/images/d/da/Fry_Looking_Squint.jpg)

Comment: Curious why you need a hole. a hole like that I mean.

Comment: I just needed to add an item in an array in a given position (let's say the 3rd) and I was wondering which was the easier way to do it (obviously I didn't know array_splice)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
function array_drill_hole($input, $start, $end) {
    array_splice($input, $start, $end - $start, null);
    return $input;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array_combine(array_merge(range(1, 2), range(4, 5)), $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
define("N", 3);

$i = count($array);
while ($i >= N) {
   $array[$i+1] = $array[$i];
   $i--;
}
unset ($array[ N ]);
```

or the equivalent *for* version

```
define("N", 3);

for($i=count($array) ; $i >= N ; $i--) {
   $array[$i+1] = $array[$i];
}
unset ($array[ N ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to join: http://codepad.org/9JDGHxhK

```
array_splice($array, 2, 0, "");

return array_filter($array);
```

Comment: OP requires an array without the index 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tested complete solution:

```
function makeHole($index,$holeArr) {
            $returnArr = array();
            $increaseFlag = false;
            foreach ($holeArr as $ind => $val) {
                if ($ind == $index || $increaseFlag) {
                    $increaseFlag = true;
                    $returnArr[$ind+1] = $val;
                } else {
                    $returnArr[$ind] = $val;
                }
            }
            return $returnArr;
        }

        $array = array(1 => 'a',
            2 => 'b',
            3 => 'c',
            4 => 'd');
        $result = makeHole(3,$array);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($result);
        echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(1 => 'a',
               2 => 'b',
               3 => 'c',
               4 => 'd');
array_splice($array, 2, 0, " ");
array_splice($array, 3, 0, " ");
unset($array[3]);
unset($array[2]);

var_dump($array);
```

Output:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "b" [4]=> string(1) "c" [5]=> string(1) "d" }
```